# Constructing a metric $\rho$ such that $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\rho)$ is a complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $S = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}.$  Construct a metric $\rho$ on $S$ such that

(1) $(S,\rho)$ is a complete metric space and

(2) for any sequence $\{s_n\}$ in $S$ and $s \in S,$ the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \rho(s_n,s) = 0$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ in $(S,\rho).$

Prove that $\rho$ satisfies both properties.

First thought was to try the discrete metric, but this violates (2).  My next idea was to use $\rho(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|},$ but I have been unable to show that this makes $(S,\rho)$ complete.  Any insight/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For a complete metric that generates the usual topology, try $$d(x,y)=|x-y|+\left|\frac1x-\frac1y\right|\;.$$

**Added:** Suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is $d$-Cauchy. Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_k,x_\ell)<\epsilon$ whenever $k,\ell\ge m_\epsilon$. But then $|x_k-x_\ell|\le d(x_k,x_\ell)<\epsilon$ whenever $k,\ell\ge m_\epsilon$, so $\sigma$ is Cauchy in the usual metric on $\Bbb R$. That metric is complete, so $\sigma$ converges to some $x\in\Bbb R$ with respect to the usual metric. To finish the argument, we must show that $x\ne 0$ and that $\sigma$ converges to $x$ with respect to $d$.

Suppose that $x=0$. By passing to a subsequence if necessary we may assume that the $x_n$ all have the same algebraic sign.

- Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{x_n}=\infty$ if the $x_n$ are positive, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{x_n}=-\infty$ if the $x_n$ are negative.
- Show that either case contradicts the hypothesis that $\sigma$ is $d$-Cauchy, because for any $m\in\Bbb N$ and positive real number $\alpha$ there are $k,\ell\ge m$ such that $$\left|\frac1{x_k}-\frac1{x_\ell}\right|>\alpha\;.$$

This shows that $x\ne 0$, and therefore also that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{x_n}=\frac1x\;.$$

Now it should be straightforward to verify that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x)=0$.

Comment: Sorry to bring this question back so late, but how might one go about showing a Cauchy sequence converges using this metric? I had revisited this problem with the idea that maybe $\rho(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ would work as a complete metric on $X = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.  I'm having some difficulty showing if either of $(X,d)$ or $(X,\rho)$ are complete.

Comment: @Merkh: I’ve expanded the answer to give an outline for that part of the proof.

Comment: @Merkh: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

That metric $\rho$ is not a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$. How do you divide by a vector? If you consider it as a metric on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, then it is not complete, since the sequence $x_n=n$ is Cauchy, but can't converge to a nonzero real number.

Comment: It wasn't my result, it was on another math.stack post.  Any suggestions for what would be a complete metric on this space?